# how Secondary indexed fields are stored?

Tags: java, cassandra

In cassandra 2.1 if i create a secondry index on map value where map is a map of (text,Address) here address is a UDT , then how will be the indexed value is stored i.e using toString or HashCode??

Answer (score 0):

At the storage level all values are byte arrays. Thus the `Address` is effectively stored as a blob.